# How can I prove the equation has unique positive real solution?

Tags: continuity, problem-solving

Without using derivative, prove that the equation
$$x^5-2x^4-3x^3-4x^2-5x-6=0$$
has unique positive real solution.

I tried, consider function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with
$$f(x)=x^5-2x^4-3x^3-4x^2-5x-6.$$
We have $f$ is a continous function and $f(0)<0$. Another way,
$$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x) = +\infty, $$
therefore there is exits a number $a >0$ such that $f(a) >0$.

Because, $f(0) \cdot f(a) <0$, therefore the equation $f(x) = 0$ has a solution $x_0 $ belongs to $(0,a)$.

Now I can not prove $x_0$ is unique solution. How can I do that without using derivative?

Ingeneral, how can I prove that the equation
$$x^n = P_{n-1}(x),$$
where, $P_{n-1}(x)$ is a polynomial of $n-1$ degree and   all positive real coefficients has unique positive real solution.

Comment: If you look up and apply Descartes’ Rule of Signs, the sequence of coefficients $(+1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6)$ tells you what you need to know. The sequence has only one sign change, so there is exactly one positive root. (Descartes’ Rule: If there are $s$ sign changes in the sequence of non-zero coefficients, the number of positive roots equals $s-2i$ for some nonnegative integer $i$.)

Answer (score 0):

If $ x<0,$ always $f(x)<0$

$f(x)=(x^2-2x-3)(x^3-1)-3(x^2+x+1)$

$=((x-1)^2-4)(x^3-1)-3(x^2+x+1)$

at least x>3 we know.$f(4)=5*63-3*25>0$

In the area of $3<x<4 $ there is an unique solution.